# \n and PHP_EOL are not creating new lines

Tags: php

I've been trying to use `\n`, `\r` and `PHP_EOL` for the past two hours and none of them are working on my **PHP** page when viewed on my Windows computer. Did I do anything wrong during installation?

I could use `<br />,` but I want to be able to use `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: If page is HTML, then <br> should be used instead of \n and \r. If you want to use \n and \r, then <pre> should be used before. If you print text into .txt file and view it via windows notepad, then \r\n should be used.

Comment: define("PHP_EOL", "<br>");

Answer (score 6):

If you are making a website / looking at a page in your browser:

These combinations will indeed not help you. While they will, in various different ways, create a new line in your *source*, the thing is that your are writing HTML.

This means that using your PHP code you are creating another piece of code in the HTML language. That code is interpreted by your browser. **Now it is the case that HTML will ignore newlines: it uses the tag `<br>` or `<br/>` for this.**

The best thing you can do is look up some of these resources in a beginners guide to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use `<br>` or other HTML formatting that will produce a new line effect. Your browser only sees the HTML on the client side, which the PHP is producing from the server side. In this case, PHP_EOL is ignored as white space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if (!defined('PHP_EOL')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\r\n");
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'MAC')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\r");
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'DAR')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
    } else {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
    }
  }
?>

<?php
  $test = "I'm a string on more" . PHP_EOL . "lines, see you me...";
  $test = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />', $test);
  echo $test;
 ?>
```

Hope this help.